# How to fix " Infinite Loop error on jumping to C code from bootloader"

Tags: c, operating-system, masm, bootloader

I am actually trying to run C code to write my operating system kernel for studying how operating systems work. I am stuck on this infinite loop when the bootloader jumps to my C code. How should I prevent this error

Although my bootloader works correctly the problem comes when my bootloader jumps to the kernel code written in C as `a.COM` program. The main thing is that the dummy code just keeps on printing a character again and again although the code must run only once. It seems as if the main code is being called again and again. Here is the code for the `startpoint.asm` assembly header and `bootmain.cpp` file.

---

Here is the code for `startpoint.asm` which is used while linking at first so that the code can be invoked automatically. (Written in *MASM* )

**Note:** The code is loaded at the address `2000H:0000H`.

```
;------------------------------------------------------------
.286                 ; CPU type
;------------------------------------------------------------
.model TINY               ; memory of model
;---------------------- EXTERNS -----------------------------
extrn        _BootMain:near     ; prototype of C func
;------------------------------------------------------------
;------------------------------------------------------------   
.code   

main:
        jmp short start     ; go to main
        nop

;----------------------- CODE SEGMENT -----------------------
start:  
        cli
        mov ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
        mov ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
        mov es,ax               ; Make ES correct
        mov ss,ax               ; Make SS correct        
        mov bp,2000h
        mov sp,2000h            ; Setup a stack
        sti
                                ; start the program 
        call           _BootMain
        ret

        END main                ; End of prog
```

---

Code for `bootmain.cpp`

```
extern "C" void BootMain()
{
    __asm
    {
         mov ah,0EH
         mov al,'G'
         int 10H
    } 
    return;
}
```

The compiling and linker commands are as follows:

Code to compile `bootmain.cpp`:

```
CL.EXE /AT /G2 /Gs /Gx /c /Zl bootmain.cpp
```

Code to compile `startpoint.asm`:

```
ML.EXE /AT /c startpoint.asm
```

Code to link them both (In preserved order):

```
LINK.EXE /T /NOD startPoint.obj bootmain.obj
```

**Expected output**:

```
G
```

Actual Output:

```
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the end of `start`.

`start` is never called -- it is jumped to directly, and it sets up the stack itself. When `_BootMain` returns, the stack is empty; the `ret` at the end of `start` will pop garbage data from above the end of the stack and attempt to jump to it. If that memory contains zeroes, program flow will return to `main`.

You need to set up something specific to happen after `_BootMain` returns. If you just want the system to hang after executing `_BootMain`, insert an infinite loop (e.g. `jmp .`) to the end of `start` instead of the erroneous `ret`.

Alternatively, consider having your bootloader set up the stack itself and `call` the COM executable. When that returns, the bootloader can take appropriate action.